# plotting data from columns from the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 60 columns of data (column 1 = I 1, column 2 = S 1.... column 3 = I 2, column 4 =S 2.. and so on)...

I want to create a function that selects two columns at a time for slicing, plotting and finding the integral of the slice. I can do this for two columns but I don't know how to implement a function to run all 60 columns. So far I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col =None)
df_slice =df.iloc[23500:25053]


R = df_slice['I 1']
I = df_slice['S 1']
rcParams['figure.figsize']= 10,5
plt.plot(R, I)
plt.xlabel('cm-1')
plt.ylabel('Hz')

#integration of peak

area = trapz(R)
print area
```

[image]

for the function:

```
def integrate_peak(filepath):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col =None)
    for row in df:
        ..........slice
        ..........overlay plots
        ..........get integral for each plot curve
```

output:

30 integral answers in a separate dataframe

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
def get_slice():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col =None)
    for i in range(1,31):
        df_slice = df.iloc[23500:25053]
        R = df_slice['I %i' %i]
        I = df_slice['S %i' %i]
        plt.plot(R,I)
        area = trapz(R)
        print area

get_slice()
```

This gives me an overlay of 30 plots, however gives me 30 values for integral (all being the same number)

Comment: Isn't is possible to do a simple loop over all columns, e.g. using `for slice in range(1,31)` and so on? To select the correct column you could then use `df_slice['I %i’  %slice] ` etc.

Comment: would be interesting how you set the integration boundaries. Furthermore, it looks like there is a second peak underneath. Do you account for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def f(col1,col2):
    print col1,col2
    R = df[col1]
    I = df[col2]
    rcParams['figure.figsize']= 10,5
    plt.plot(R, I)
    plt.xlabel('cm-1')
    plt.ylabel('Hz')
    area = np.trapz(R)
    print area
    return col2
reduce(lambda x,y:f(x,y),df)
plt.show()
```

For processing (col1,col2) then (col2,col3) and so on.

Comment: I want the function to select the columns for me and compute the integral of a slice(of that data) for 60 columns not 2. You have basically created a function that does what my code does but only for one set of data.

Comment: Look at reduce. This code will give you an overlay of (number of columns) graphs and will print the same amount of different integrals, isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, i have found the solution.

```
def get_slice():
        area_list = []
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col =None)
        Raman = df['I 1']
        Intensity = df['S 1']

        for i in range(1,31):
            df_slice = df.iloc[23500:25053]
            R = df_slice['I %i' %i]
            I = df_slice['S %i' %i]
            for i in R:
                area = trapz(R, x = I)
            area_list.append(area)
        a = np.mean(area_list)
```